# access enum class properties which defined in struct inside a function in c++

Tags: c++, struct, enums

How to access struct properties which defined in enum class. 
The error is "error: 'e' is not a class,namespace,or enumeration"

```
enum class pay_type
{
    hourly, salary
};

struct employee
{
    string first_name;        
    string last_name;         
    pay_type pay_kind;        
    double pay_unit_amount;   
};

istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, employee& e)
{

    is >> e.first_name;
    is >> e.last_name;
    if (e.pay_kind == pay_type::hourly && e.pay_kind == pay_type::salary)
    {
        is >> e::pay_kind;
    }

    is >> e.pay_unit_amount;
    return is;
}
```

Comment: Objects of enumeration type are normal objects. And they're normal members, too. Access them via the dot-operator

Comment: Your condition is wrong, `pay_kind` can not be both values at once, it can be one ***or*** the other.

Comment: As for your error, *where* do you get the error? Can you please edit your question to include the *complete* and *unedited* error log? And also to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that replicates the error.

Comment: when I try       is >> e.pay_kind    I got two different error messages error: cannot bind 'std::istream {aka std:basic_istream<char>} lvalue to "std:basic_istream <char>&&"'

Comment: error: cannot bind ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_istream<char>&&’|

Comment: /usr/include/c++/4.8/istream|872|error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = pay_type]’|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is:

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, employee& e)
{

    is >> e.first_name;
    is >> e.last_name;

    // Read the pay kind as an integer.
    // Check to make sure that the value is acceptable.

    int payKind;
    is >> payKind;    
    if (payKind == pay_type::hourly || payKind == pay_type::salary)
    {
       e.pay_kind = static_cast<pay_type>(payKind);
    }
    else
    {
       // Deal with error condition
    }

    is >> e.pay_unit_amount;
    return is;
}
```